# Help understanding Cantor's Theorem

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am having trouble understanding the proof of Cantor's Theorem:

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_Theorem

http://www.whitman.edu/mathematics/higher_math_online/section04.10.html

The part that confuses me is this set

$$A = \{ x \in S \mid x \not \in f(x) \}$$

Can someone explain what this is saying in plain English. I am reading it as the set of elements $x$ that are in $S$ but not in $P(S)$, or that are in $S$ but cannot be mapped to $P(S)$.

My thinking is that every element in $S$ is a subset of $P(S)$, by the definition of power set.  Every element in $S$ CAN be mapped to $P(S)$, so that set $A$ must be the empty set? Why not?

Can someone help clarify this?

Comment: First of all, I think you should think about power sets a little more. If $x$ is in $S$, then $x$ is NOT a subset of $P(S)$. For example, if $S = \{1,2\}$, then $P(S) = \{ \emptyset, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{1,2\} \}$. So the element 1, for example, is not a subset of $P(S)$. It's not even an element of $P(S)$!! However, $\{1\}$ is an element of $P(S)$. I think getting that  straight will be helpful in understanding the proof.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The point is that $f$ takes an element of $S$ and returns a subset of $S$. And now we define $A$ to be the set of those which are not elements of the sets they are mapped to.

What is $A$ *exactly*? Well that depends greatly on the set $S$ and the function $f$. Let's consider two examples.

The first, take $f(x)=\{x\}$, then for every $x\in S$ it is true that $x\in f(x)$. Therefore $A=\varnothing$. But it is true that there is no $x$ such that $f(x)=\varnothing$!

In the second example, take $f(x)=S\setminus\{x\}$, then for every $x\in S$ it is true that $x\notin f(x)$. Therefore $A=S$. But in this case it is true that there is no $x$ such that $f(x)=S$!

In both examples we see that $A$, which depends very much on the function $f$, is not in its range. And that's the point of the theorem. If $f\colon S\to\mathcal P(S)$, then $f$ is not surjective.

Comment: Thank you, you helped me. I think the secret to understanding this is to take a simple example and apply the proof to it (S=  {1,2}). Then take a slightly harder example and try it for that case, because something slightly different will happen (S= {1,2,3}). Then take a harder example (S= natural numbers) and apply the proof. Next look at the proof for the general case with no example, and it should make sense.

Answer (score 2):

It is a version of the Russell paradox except with a function.

Comment: Without more explanation, this seems more like a comment than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the secret to the proof is to understand that $A = \{x \in S: x \not \in f(x) \}$ can be an intelligent way to define S. In the best case scenario you have an A that includes all x in S. Under that best scenario S itself cannot be mapped to, because we have the condition $x \not \in f(x)$, which doesn't allow us to pick an f(x) where x is include (like would happen if we mapped s to the entire set S).

We assumed we had a surjection function f that mapped S to P(S). We found a subset of S called A but we cannot find a way to point from S to A and we should be able because A is a subset of S. We need to be able to point to every subset of S this is a contradiction and our assumption that we had a surjection f that mapped from S to P(S) is wrong.

Comment: You don't need to assume that you had a surjection. You assume that $f$ is any function from $S$ to its power set, then you find a witness for the fact that $f$ is not surjective. You will also note that $A$ need not be equal to $S$, as the first example in my answer shows, so it can't really be "an intelligent way of defining $S$".